# Is display none gives value on $_POST?

Tags: php

```
<div style="display:none">
   <input type='text' name='test_val' value='5'>
</div>



<div>
       <input type='text' name='test_val' value='10'>
    </div>
```

which value of test_val will be POST?

Comment: need to give id and name for a input field and then check it will come..<input type='text' name="xx" id="xx" value='10'>

Comment: Add a name attribute to both and test it out!

Comment: Input that are not visible (in case of display:none for example), also will affect post parameters.

Comment: I realize that display:none gives value on post. Last value for that name will be get on POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding field in any way won't hide the value. If you want to prevent value from being sent, your field has to have "disabled" attribute. If you want to access both fields values (and have a same name) then you have to update your names. For example:

```
<div style="display:none">
   <input type='text' name='test_val[]' value='5'>
</div>

<div>
  <input type='text' name='test_val[]' value='10'>
</div>
```

Then, in PHP you can access your field values:

```
$_POST['test_val'][0] == 5
$_POST['test_val'][1] == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You will get output like below
```

Array
(
    [test_val] => 10
)